# How to plot ROC if result is in text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, roc

My program results in text (notepad) file, I want to plot FAR Vs FRR and EER Vs Threshold. Following is the result.

FAR,     FRR,     Accuracy,    EER,    Threshold

21.3248   46.6667   78.0417    21.9583    0.5467

23.5897   41.6667   75.9583    24.0417    0.5007

25.7265   40.8333   73.8958    26.1042    0.5168

28.8889   50.8333   70.5625    29.4375    0.5591

26.9658   43.3333   72.6250    27.3750    0.3973

17.0085   50.8333   82.1458    17.8542    0.4310

22.9274   43.3333   76.5625    23.4375    0.3339

16.0470   46.6667   83.1875    16.8125    0.4013

16.4530   43.3333   82.8750    17.1250    0.5091

18.8462   41.6667   80.5833    19.4167    0.5055

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load your data using:

```
load data.txt
result = data;
```

After that, you plot your ROC by referring to the following code:

```
plotroc(targets,outputs)
plotroc(targets1,outputs2,'name1',...)
```

you may see here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/plotroc.html

Comment: Error using load
Unknown text on line number 2 of ASCII file result.txt
"FAR".

Error in roc (line 1)
 load result.txt;